# Angular/RxJS How do I use observable pipe to generate ajax call hierarchy but return a single response?

Tags: angularjs, rxjs

I am writing an angular service that calls an API endpoint to get some basic metadata for an object.  My struggle is around having to complete 2 API calls to get all of the data that I need.  The first API call returns a list of object ID's, and the second API call uses those ID's to get the data.

I need to map over the entries array returned by getFiles and call another endpoint to get the data.  I don't want the subscribers to get a bunch of different responses and have to build an object on their end, I want a single response.

```
//getFiles response
{
    total_count: 2
    offset: 0,
    limit: 30,
    entries: [{ id: '1' }, { id: '2' }]
}

getFiles() {
    return this.http('call my endpoint')
}

getFileDetails(fileId) {
    return this.http('call my endpoint using fileId')
}

getFilesWithDetails() {
    this.getFiles()
        .pipe(
            // ????
        );
}
```

I want my consumers of the service to call `getFilesWithDetails` and have it return hydrated files.  Is this possible?

Comment: You will need to `getFileDetails` to accept an array instead of a string

Comment: @Hosar I was planning to use switchMap or something to iterate over the entries.  I would like to keep my `getFileDetails` as an atomic operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` to obtain an array of file details from an array of file ids and you can then use `mergeMap` to emit the array of details into the observable stream:

```js
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';

getFilesWithDetails() {
    return this.getFiles().pipe(
        mergeMap(result => forkJoin(
            result.entries.map(e => this.getFileDetails(e.id))
        ))
    );
}
```

`forkJoin` accepts an array of observables and emits an array that contains the last emitted value for each of the passed observables.